# Display content "overflows" when using fractional scaling

Tags: display, display-resolution, 21.10

I have Ubuntu 21.10 running on Razer Blade 14" laptop and connected to an external LG 4K monitor, using NVIDIA proprietary drivers.

The default 100% scaling looks good on the laptop monitor but things are too small on the external 4K display. 200% with fractional scaling disabled looks good on the monitor (a little bit too big maybe) but huge on the laptop, I can't seem to have per monitor scaling with fractional switched off.

If I switch fractional scaling on, and try to go for the intermediate values, like 150%, something weird happens (see screenshot). The topbar with the date and time that's supposed to be in the middle, is slightly right. And the top right stuff with the volume and battery level it's just not there, it's like it is off screen somehow. It looks like if the scaling actually were 200% but the content is overflowing (? not sure what the right term is) the display.

Anyone run into this issue before, I can't seem to find much info about it. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I also saw this issue, so I report a bug.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1966050